# How to change the Existing Dialog in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, custom, sharepoint-calendar, dialog

I need to replace my custom dialog instead of Existing Add event dialogue in calendar list,  Instead of this dialog [image]

I need to replace my custom dialog.I tried this script for disabling the dialog

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function expandCal() {
  setInterval(expandCalCheck, 900);
}
function expandCalCheck() {
   $(".ms-acal-vcont a[title='Add']").attr("href","NewForm.aspx");   
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(expandCal, "sp.ui.applicationpages.calendar.js");
</script>
```

But I am not sure how to replace the existing dialog,  Please suggest me some idea to achieve this?

Comment: Can you be more clear ? You want to a custom the Add event dialog or you want to customize OOTB dialog ? If possible, please add some screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question @GautamSheth